# Upserting with SQLAlchemy into Postgres to Table with a '.' in the name

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, upsert

I am trying to upsert into a postgres table where some of the columns have a '.' in their name.
example column names: country.name.
It would be best not to change the column name.

When I try to do this I get an error.

```
def upsert(df: DataFrame, engine: sql_engine) -> None:
  with engine.connect() as conn:
    base = automap_base()
    base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, schema="some_schema")
    table1= Table('table1', base.metadata,
                      autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, schema="some_schema")
    stmt = insert(table1).values(df.to_dict('records'))
    conn.execute(stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
        constraint='table1_pkey',
        set_=dict(country.name=stmt.excluded.country.name
                  )))
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

I was trying to follow this recipe which was working fine until the name of the columns had a '.'
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#updating-using-the-excluded-insert-values

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The sqlalchemy statement contains a excluded field where all the columns are, if you use this then it will work.
I created a "updated_dict" where all the columns names and object are from the excluded column. I filter out the primary keys.
This way it won't matter how the name of the columns are constructed.

```
def upsert(df: DataFrame, engine: sql_engine) -> None:
  with engine.connect() as conn:
    base = automap_base()
    base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, schema="some_schema")
    table1= Table('table1', base.metadata,
                      autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, schema="some_schema")
    stmt = insert(table1).values(df.to_dict('records'))

    update_dict = {
        c.name: c
        for c in stmt.excluded
        if not c.primary_key
        }

    conn.execute(stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
        constraint='table1_pkey',
        set_=update_dict ))
```